# How to sort a text file out, Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, split

Here is the text -

CAR,Peugot,3008,12500

CAR,BMW,316,4995

CAR,Ford,Fiesta,2995

I wish to sort this out and show the cheapest car. But first i need to split the text out.
Now i know you can do text.split("\r\n"); but this isnt working. Any ideas ?

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class Vehicle {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
    {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/java/car_file.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        String text = "";
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line!= null)
        {
            text += line;
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        System.out.println(text);

        String words[] = text.split(",|\r\n| ");
        int count=words.length;
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't seem to split it on newline is because when you call `reader.readLine()`, it removes the newline.

For instance, say you have this:

```
line one\nline two\n
```

In your text editor, you see this:

```
line one
line two
```

if you `String s = ""; s += reader.readLine(); s += reader.readLine();`, you will end up adding "line one" the first time and "line two" the second time, for a new String of `line oneline two`.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class Vehicle {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
    {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/java/car_file.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        String text = "";
        String line = reader.readLine() +"\n";
        while (line!= null)
        {
            text += line;
            line = reader.readLine() +"\n";
        }

        System.out.println(text);

        String lines[] = text.split("\n");
        int count = lines.length;
        System.out.println(count);

        for(String line : lines) {
            String words[] = line.split(",");
            <<do something with words array>>
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind this isn't the best way to parse this. There are CSV reader libraries readily available if you do a quick search on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You may take an `ArrayList of String` instead of `Array of String` , and do it like :

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
while (line!= null)
    {
        words.add(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
int count=words.size();
    System.out.println(count);
```

OR, if you don't want to use List, You can do it like:

```
while (line!= null)
    {
        text += line+"#";
        line = reader.readLine();
    }

    System.out.println(text);

    String words[] = text.split("#");
    int count=words.length;
    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: yes. thankyou. i understand now i was reading it in line by line and where you put " text += line+"#"; " helped me understand this. instead of "#" i put "\r\n" which printed out to console the same as it is in the txt.doc. thanks

Answer (score 0):

better to split each line in loop:

```
List<String[]> lineFields = new ArrayList<>();
while (line != null) {
  list.add(line.split(",");
  line = reader.readLine();
}
```

and then process the list.